# exactly at once for end-to-end

Tags: apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, flink-streaming

I am wondering that it is possible to achieve end-to-end exactly at once semantics using Flink?

My data pipeline looks as below.

First scenario
source : kafka
process : flink
sink : kafka

Second scenario
source : kafka
process : flink
sink : database (mysql or redis)

Look forward to your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's an Immerok recipe that explains in detail how to achieve exactly-once semantics with Apache Flink and Apache Kafka. You can find it at https://www.docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/exactly-once-with-apache-kafka-and-apache-flink/

Disclaimer: I work for Immerok